# How to Enable embedding Wordpress default gallery in comments?

Tags: shortcode, gallery, embed

I want to embed WordPress default gallery in comments which has embed code like this:

```
[gallery link="file" columns="2" size="medium" ids="1,2"]
```

To do so, I added this code which enables shortcodes in the comments:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'do_shortcode' )
```

But someone suggested that is not a secure way to do so. Hence, how should I enable shortcodes in comments the right way or for now I can manage with only gallery shortcode too if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, if you allow all kinds of shortcodes to be used in comments, you do not know what effects you get. It might even become a security issue if you have powerful shortcodes installed (perhaps even without knowing it, as a feature you do not use). So, the trick is to selectively allow certain shortcodes. First, let's add a filter to [`get_comment_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_text/) (other than `comment_text` this will also affect your comments feed).

```
add_filter ('get_comment_text','wpse334485_filter_shortcodes',10,3);
```

Now we must make sure that this filter will apply *only* the gallery filter. That is, we need to strip all shortcodes from the comment except the gallery shortcode. Here we go:

```
function wpse334485_filter_shortcodes ($comment_text, $comment, $args) {
  $comment_text = strip_shortcodes ($comment_text);
  return do_shortcode ($comment_text);
  }
```

The above code will strip all shortcodes, so it's not complete. Luckily the [`strip_shortcodes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) function has a filter which allows you to influence which tags are removed. Here it is:

```
add_filter ('strip_shortcodes_tagnames','wpse334485_allow_gallery_shortcode',10,2);
function wpse334485_allow_gallery_shortcode ($tags_to_remove, $comment_text) {
  return array ('[gallery]');
  }
```

Note that I didn't test this code, so some debugging may be necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing an answer. I added all above code to theme `functions.php`. I think till the stripping part code is working. I removed the code `add_filter( 'comment_text', 'do_shortcode' )` so the embed code was displaying as raw in comment content.

After adding the above code, the embed code disappeared from comment text. I am not sure how do I debug further. Can you advise?

Comment: I checked the global `shortcode_tags` variable and apparently the []-brackets are part of the array key. I updated the answer to reflect that. You could echo the `$tags_to_remove` variable inside the last filter to see what exactly is parsed there and make sure what you return from the filter is formatted in the same way.

Comment: Brilliant :) That worked. `[gallery]` was correct although I didn't test it via echo.

Also, can you please tell me if I had to allow another shortcode in the future, how do I add multiple shortcodes in the above code?

Comment: Well, in the last filter you return an array, so you could add more shortcodes there

Comment: Like: 

`return array ('[code1]');
return array ('[code2]');`

This way?

Comment: No like `return array ('[gallery]','[whatever]')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That will do.